# how to get the right gperf samples report

Tags: gperftools

I have some `gperf tool` files:

the first one was running about 2 minites,file is **18M**;

others running about 2 hours and the files are about **800M**

when I try to use :`pprof --text` to get the report, found the the first one has **1300** samples but these 2 hours running just **5500** samples.

I excepted the larger files have about `2*3600*100 samples`(because "*by default the gperf tools take 100 samples a second*").

The same procedures and the same operating environment, why the samples too few?
sorry for my poor english.

Comment: Try 'CPUPROFILE_REALTIME=1' environment parameter of cpuprofiler - https://gperftools.googlecode.com/git/doc/cpuprofile.html Also, file size will be huge if there is deep stack... (PS: it can be more useful not to do Mike-styled manual sampling, but to try recent `perf` profiler)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looks like it's I/O bound. In the 120-second job, you're getting 13 seconds of samples. In the 120-minute job, you're getting about 1 minute of samples. The actual fraction of time spent computing vs. I/O can vary pretty widely, especially if there is some constant startup overhead.

If the time ought to be roughly linear in file size, that 120-minute job should really only be about 40 minutes, so I would do some [*manual sampling*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/23771) on the big job, to see what's happening.